# why is chrome unity launcher launching a live preview from brackets?

Tags: unity, google-chrome, launcher, icons, adobe-brackets

so firstly i saw another user as this same question a few months ago and no one answered that one, but i hope my luck will be different.

i have brackets. i have chrome which i use as my primary browser. ubuntu 16.04lts. now, today, each time i hit the unity launcher icon for chrome, it attempts to produce a live preview from a file i am working on in brackets (adobe brackets, an ide if your not familliar).

i have purged brackets, i have purged chrome. i have reinstalled chrome and it still happens.

i have gone into `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome-stable.desktop` and the only thing it does is launch `google-chrome-stable`.

if i go to the command line and type `google-chrome` it launches appropriately.

**could this be a symbolic link somehow accidentally got created bewteen the unity launcher icon for chrome and brackets live preview? if so how would i go about finding and destroying that linke?**

again brackets is uninstalled so i dont suspect it is brackets to blame at this point.

Answer (score 1):

i figured out the problem if anyone else has a similar problem, apparently there is another file that contains the `.desktop` files, which takes precedence over the `/usr/share/applications/` directory of `.desktop` files, and that is located at `~/.local/share/applications`, and for some reason the `google-chrome.desktop` file was set to open a brackets preview. dont know why that happened still but deleting it was enough to solve the problem anyhow.